# Need to save latitude and longitude send via whatsapp location in twilio

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I need to save/ show  latitude and longitude send via Whatsapp location in Twilio.
Right now i am able to store text messages but unable to read WhatsApp location

Comment: Welcome to SO, you have presented us with your part of the research or your code, please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly for Python but in Node.js if a *"Location"* is attached to a Whatsapp message, it will be present in the POST request parameters and you can get its properties similarly with how you get the body of the message.

If you get the message with `req.body.Body` then if a location is attached you'll have available as strings

- `req.body.Latitude`
- `req.body.Longitude`
- `req.body.Address`

otherwise they'll be *"undefined"*.

In the request body they look something like this:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  Latitude: '37.389958280680645',
  Longitude: '-122.08166124764976',
  Address: '500 Castro St, Mountain View, CA 94041',
  Label: 'Bean Scene Cafe'
  ...
}
```

Again, I have not tried in Python but maybe is something like this:

```py
message_latitude = request.values.get('Latitude', None)
message_longitude = request.values.get('Longitude', None)
message_address = request.values.get('Address', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent blog post announcing this capability, https://www.twilio.com/blog/new-rich-features-support-deeper-customer-engagement-twilio-api-whatsapp.

The blog references this documentation for more details on implementation.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#send-a-location-message-with-whatsapp